# Lightning : Drop down list isnt showing

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
 <aura:component controller="ActionController"  implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="theId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="wrplst" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String"/>

<aura:attribute name="Components" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="Components1" type="List"/>

<aura:handler name="deleteJob" event="c:deleteJobEvt" action="{!c.RemoveClick}" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<p>
    <center><h5><b>Creating Action Criteria </b></h5></center>
</p>
<h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">
    <b>
        <I> Action Criteria</I>
    </b>
</h3>
<table >
    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
        <th class="head">
            <I>Action</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Object Name</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Component</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Operator</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator * Value</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator / Value</I>
        </th>
    </tr>

    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.wrplst.length > 0}">
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst}" var="a">
            <c:NewAction wrp="{!a}" options="{!v.options}" Components="{!v.Components}"  Components1="{!v.Components1}" selectedValue=""  idval="{!v.theId}"/>
         </aura:iteration>
    </aura:renderIf>
</table>
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Add row" onclick="{!c.AddRow}" />
<lightning:button variant="brand"  label="Save" onclick="{!c.saveRow}" />
```

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.pageLoad(component);
    helper.componentVal(component);

},
doSomething: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.Method2(component);
},
RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {
    var selCont = event.getParam("selectedJob");
    var conts = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var contsval = JSON.stringify(conts);

    var Selndex = conts.indexOf(selCont);

    var DeleteLen = conts.length;
    //alert('deleteLen value::::' + DeleteLen);
    var removeAction=component.get("c.removeRow");
    removeAction.setParams({
        "wrvalue":contsval,
        "rowval":Selndex 
    });
    removeAction.setCallback(this, function(g) {
        var state = g.getState();
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
            alert('success value');
            component.set("v.wrplst",JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
        }
        else if(state==='error'){
            alert('error value');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(removeAction);
},
AddRow: function(component, event, helper) {
    var xzz=component.get("v.Components");
    alert('xzzz value :::::'+xzz);
    var comp1 = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var compJson1 = JSON.stringify(comp1);
    var mapRecords = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < comp1.length; i++) {
        mapRecords.push(comp1[i]);
    }
    var len = mapRecords.length;

    var newlen = len + 1;

    var addAction = component.get("c.addRow");
    addAction.setParams({
        "wrapval": compJson1,
        "counterval": newlen,
    });
    addAction.setCallback(this, function(res) {
        var state = res.getState();
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(res.getReturnValue()));
        } else if (state == 'ERROR') {
            alert('error');
        } else if (state == 'INCOMPLETE') {
            alert('incompltete');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(addAction);
},
saveRow: function(component, event, helper) {
    var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
    alert('Id value ::::' + Idx);
    var com = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var comJson = JSON.stringify(com);

    var saveAction = component.get("c.saveCall");
    saveAction.setParams({
        "wrvalue": comJson,
        "id": Idx,
    });
    saveAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
        var state = re.getState();
        if (state === 'SUCCESS') {

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(saveAction);
}
});
```

---

```
({
pageLoad: function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.pageLoading");
    var self = this;
    var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
    action.setParams({
        "id": Idx
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(g) {
        var state = g.getState();
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {

            component.set("v.wrplst",JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
            self.Method2(component);

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

},

Method2: function(component, event, helper) {

    var comp = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var compJson = JSON.stringify(comp);
    var Id1 = component.get("v.theId");
    var compAction = component.get("c.getComponent");
    compAction.setParams({
        "wrapval":compJson,
        "id": Id1,
    });
    compAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
        var state = re.getState();
        if (state ==='SUCCESS') {
            alert('sucesss');
            var obj=re.getReturnValue();
            alert('obj values:::::'+obj);
            //var obj = { "specialOperatorValue":"test1","specialOperatorSlashValue":null,"SpecialOperator":null,"SelObjectName":null,"record":null,"Operator":null,"ObjectApiNAme":null,"index":null,"FieldName":null,"criteriaMaster":{"attributes":{"type":"Criteria_Master__c"}},"CriteriaMasId":null,"CriteriaMas":null,"ComponentsInWpr":null,"Components1":[{"value":"CTC_Amount__c","label":"CTC Amount","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"CTC_Variable_Pay__c","label":"CTC Variable Pay","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false}],"Components":[{"value":"a0A6F00000hpHInUAM","label":"ESI","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hqqaRUAQ","label":"FBP - CH","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATKUA2","label":"Basic - CH","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATLUA2","label":"Basic - Arrears","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATMUA2","label":"HRA - CH","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATNUA2","label":"HRA - Arrears","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATOUA2","label":"Conveyance Allowance","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATPUA2","label":"Conveyance Allow-Arrears","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATQUA2","label":"Education Allowance","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATRUA2","label":"Education Allow-Arrears","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAU8UAM","label":"Festival Adv Deduction","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAU9UAM","label":"Insurance","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUAUA2","label":"Car Value","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUCUA2","label":"ESI - Employer","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUDUA2","label":"Professional Tax","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUEUA2","label":"Hard Furnishings - Reimb","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUFUA2","label":"LTA - Reimbursement - CH","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUGUA2","label":"Medical Reimbursement - CH","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUHUA2","label":"Telephone Exp. - Reimb","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATSUA2","label":"Supplementary Allowance","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATTUA2","label":"Suppl Allow-Arrears","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATUUA2","label":"Exgratia","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATVUA2","label":"Leave Encashment","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATWUA2","label":"Incentive","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATXUA2","label":"Notice Pay","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATYUA2","label":"Retention Bonus","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATZUA2","label":"Other Earnings","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATaUAM","label":"Bonus","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATbUAM","label":"Gratuity Payment","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATcUAM","label":"Gratuity","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATdUAM","label":"Superannuation","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATeUAM","label":"Statutory Bonus","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATfUAM","label":"Night Working Allowance","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATgUAM","label":"Referral Incentive","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAThUAM","label":"Miscellaneous Earnings","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATiUAM","label":"Salary Advance Payment","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATjUAM","label":"Unclaimed Reimbursement","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATkUAM","label":"Festival Advance","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATlUAM","label":"Basic - Recovery","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATmUAM","label":"HRA - Recovery","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUIUA2","label":"Petrol - Reimb","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUJUA2","label":"Driver Salary - Reimb","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUKUA2","label":"Net","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAULUA2","label":"Gross","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUMUA2","label":"CTC","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUNUA2","label":"Net","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUOUA2","label":"Gross","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAUPUA2","label":"Total Deduction","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATnUAM","label":"Conveyance - Recovery","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAToUAM","label":"Education Allow - Recover","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATpUAM","label":"Suppl Allow - Recovery","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATqUAM","label":"Night Shift AllowRecovery","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATrUAM","label":"Salary Advance - Recovery","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATsUAM","label":"Notice Pay - Recovery","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATtUAM","label":"Excess Paid Reimbursement","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATuUAM","label":"Provident Fund","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATvUAM","label":"Employer Pension Scheme","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATwUAM","label":"Provident Fund - Employer","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATxUAM","label":"Account 21","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATyUAM","label":"Account 22","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpATzUAM","label":"V P F","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAU0UAM","label":"N P S","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAU1UAM","label":"Income Tax","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAU2UAM","label":"Labour Welfare Fund","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAU3UAM","label":"Loan Deduction","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAU4UAM","label":"Car Lease","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAU5UAM","label":"Miscellaneous Deductions","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAU6UAM","label":"Other Recovery","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAU7UAM","label":"Transport Deduction","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAxmUAE","label":"Variable Pay","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false},{"value":"a0A6F00000hpAxrUAE","label":"Special Allowance","escapeItem":false,"disabled":false}],"componentMap1":null,"componentMap":null};
            //var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
            // alert('myJson value ::::'+myJSON);
            var objs= JSON.parse(obj);
            alert('objs value ::::'+objs);
            console.log('::::::::objs value::::'+objs);
            var s=objs.Components1;
            alert('s value:::::'+s);
            var myJSON2 = JSON.stringify(objs.Components1);
            alert('myJSON2 values :::::'+myJSON2);
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(myJSON2);
            var compo=[];
            var compos=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) 
            {

                var counter = jsonData[i].label;
                alert(counter);
                compo.push(jsonData[i].label);

                component.set("v.Components1",compo);

            }
            alert('components 1 value ::::::'+compo);
            var myJSON3 = JSON.stringify(objs.Components);
            var jsonData1 = JSON.parse(myJSON3);
            for (var i = 0; i <jsonData1.length; i++) 
            {

                var counter = jsonData1[i].label;
                //alert(counter);
                compos.push(counter);

            } 
            alert('components  value:::::::::::::'+compos);
            component.set("v.Components",compos);
        }
        else if(state==='error'){
            alert('error value');
        }
            else if(state==='INCOMPLETE'){
                alert('incomplete values:::');

            }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(compAction);
},
componentVal:function(component,event,helper){
    var action=component.get("c.ObjectNames");
    action.setCallback(this,function(re){
        var state=re.getState();
        if(state==='SUCCESS'){

            component.set("v.options",JSON.parse(re.getReturnValue()));
        }
        else if(state==='Error'){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

================================================================================
NewComponet:

```
<aura:component controller="ActionController" >
<aura:attribute name="wrp" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="idval" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute required="true" name="options" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="Components" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="Components1" type="List"/>

<aura:attribute required="true" name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="wpchange" type="List" />
<aura:registerEvent name="deleteJob" type="c:deleteJobEvt"/>

<tr>
    <td class="cell" style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
        <p >
            <button type="button" onclick="{!c.RemoveClick}" >remove</button>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cell" >
        <p>
          <lightning:select name="mySelect" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme}" aura:id="obc" onchange="{!c.dosomething}">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
                <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select> 
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cell" >

        <p>
            <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.Operator}">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Pay_Element_Master__c',
                                 v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='CTC_Master__c', 
                                 v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Section_Master__c')}">
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!(v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='CTC_Master__c')}">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Components}" var="it">
                        <option text="{!it.label}" selected="{!it.selected}"/>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!(v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Pay_Element_Master__c')}">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Components1}" var="its">
                        <option text="{!its.label}" selected="{!its.selected}"/>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </aura:if>
            </lightning:select>
        </p>

    </td>

    <td class="cell" >
        <p>
            <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.Operator}">
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="+ Addition">+ Addition</option>
                <option value="- Subtract  ">- Subtract</option>
                <option value="* Multiply ">* Multiply</option>
                <option value="/ Divide">/ Divide</option>
            </lightning:select>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cell" >
        <p>
            <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.SpecialOperator}">
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="*">*</option>
                <option value="*/">*/</option>
                <option value="/">/</option>
            </lightning:select>
        </p>
    </td>

    <td class="cell"  style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
        <p>
            <ui:inputText value="{!v.wrp.specialOperatorValue}"/>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cell"  style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
        <p>
            <ui:inputText value="{!v.wrp.specialOperatorSlashValue}"/>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

```
({
    RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {

        var event1 = component.getEvent("deleteJob");

        event1.setParams({
            'selectedJob': component.get("v.wrp"),
        });
        event1.fire();
    },
    dosomething:function(component, event, helper) {
        var x=component.find("obc").get("v.value");
        alert('x value::::'+x);
        var comp = component.get("v.wrp");
        var compJson = JSON.stringify(comp);
        alert('compJson val ::::'+compJson);
        var Id1 = component.get("v.idval");
        alert('Id1 val::::::'+Id1);

        var Action = component.get("c.getComponent");
        Action.setParams({
            "wrapval": compJson,
            "id": Id1,
        });
        Action.setCallback(this, function(re) {
            var state = re.getState();
            if (state ==='SUCCESS') {
                alert('sucess value :::');
                alert('values::::::::'+re.getReturnValue());

            }
            else if(state==='error'){
                alert('error value');
            }
                else if(state==='INCOMPLETE'){
                    alert('incomplete values:::');

                }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(Action); 
    }
  })
```

*components and components1 shows value in javascript side...but its not visible in  dropdownlist*

***components1 value***

[image]

***components value:***

[image]

Comment: you are not getting any of the select list or a particular  select list? there are three select in your component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can setup "v.options" for both component 1 and component pass the list of return values and populate to iteration and see.And also check "wrp" attribute has some values after your component init.Because it doesn't all your option will get skipped.

Comment: itsnot working..i didnt get what you are going to say can you please expand it

Comment: you have three select list in that you used v.options in on list.Just set the v.options in the callback method for the component1 and component list and set  it  in v.options and try to iterate and see.If it does not works.Then check the aura:if you are using in that, you used wrap attribute just put console.log for the attribute and see after component initalization whether you are getting any values